# Glossaries error: \glossariescaption already defined

Tags: glossaries

I trying to use the glossaries package in my dissertation document, but when I load the package I have the following error

```
usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries- 
portuges/glossaries-portuges-utf8.ldf, line 66
LaTeX Error: Command \glossariescaptionsportuges already defined.

Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.66 }

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

Anyone could help with this? 
Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a list of all packages used in your preamble (unless you are certain it is unrelated...then please omit)?  The document class is also good to know.

Comment: The `glossaries-portuges-utf8.ldf` file defines `\glossariescaptionsportuges` with `\newcommand`, so the error indicates the command has already been defined before that file was input. It's possible that something is causing that file to be input more than once. All the `glossaries-*.ldf` files are loaded with `\RequireGlossariesLang`, which should prevent multiple input, so something strange has happened, but it's hard to say without a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Thank you both @NicolaTalbot and whatisit. The problem was with the document class because I was defining as portuguese. As soon as I removed the portuguese entry the issue was solved.